# Unknown email address showing in a contact card

Tags: contacts, sync, email

I have a contacts issue. My wife, lets call her Jane Doe for example, is showing an unknown email address in her contact card on my Android phone. It shows her actual address then a second bogus one.

Jane.Doe@gmail.com which is correct but then a second one shows as JaneDoe@gmail.com and this email address has never existed.

This bogus email address doesn't show in my Gmail contacts under her name on the web browser interface and also she has a Google+ acount again with only the correct email address showing.

It only shows up in my Android phone and if I edit contact, i.e. edit the contact info stored on my phone the bogus email address disappears and cannot be edited suggesting its pulled in from another source.

The Android contact links consist of only the local (synced) Google contact, the Google+ contact and the Whatsapp contact that only contains the name and mobile number info.

Comment: Dots are ignored in Gmail addresses. `jane.doe@gmail.com` is the same as `janedoe@gmail.com` is the same as `j.a.n.e.d.o.e@gmail.com`.